Ubuntu 24.04 - 64bits - Install wine32:i386
These commands was executed previously
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Now, Wine recommends me to install wine32:i386 so I proceed to install it, but it shows me all this message. I proceed to install it, but it shows me all this message.
    gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install wine32:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas activity-log-manager aha apg apt-config-icons-large apt-config-icons-large-hidpi bamfdaemon breeze-cursor-theme

... output shortened; see revision history for full output ...

  xserver-common xserver-xorg-legacy xsettingsd yelp-xsl zeitgeist-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386

... output shortened; see revision history for full output ...

  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:i386 opencl-icd:i386 wine32-preloader:i386
Recommended packages:
  libgl1-amber-dri:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 | vdpau-driver:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  appimagelauncher bluedevil breeze cheese chrome-gnome-shell code colord default-jdk default-jre doomsday doomsday-common drkonqi endeavour evince

... output shortened; see revision history for full output ...

  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xwayland yelp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386

... output shortened; see revision history for full output ...

  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 pipewire-alsa pipewire-audio va-driver-all:i386 wine32:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core xserver-common
3 upgraded, 223 newly installed, 470 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 272 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2361 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

It asks me to remove some packages that I usually use like "gitkraken, chrome, and others". How can I install wine32 but not delete the packages I need?
Trying to upgrade shows this:
gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  file-roller python3-distupgrade shotwell shotwell-common ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

Only 6 packages.

Here the output
gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.



gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                 
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.


gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt show wine32
Package: wine32:i386
Version: 9.0~repack-4build3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/otherosfs
Source: wine
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Wine Party <debian-wine@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 752 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38), libwine (= 9.0~repack-4build3)
Recommends: wine (= 9.0~repack-4build3)
Suggests: wine32-preloader (= 9.0~repack-4build3)
Homepage: https://www.winehq.org
Download-Size: 272 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe i386 Packages
Description: Windows API implementation - 32-bit binary loader
 Wine is a free MS-Windows API implementation.
 .
 This package provides the binary loader for 32-bit Windows applications.


gonzalesc@puccohp:~/Descargas$ LC_ALL=C winetricks 
Executing cd /usr/bin
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Unknown file arch of /usr/bin/wine.
------------------------------------------------------

Regards

Are you using the WineHQ repository or the ones provided by the Ubuntu Repositories?

The problem here lies somewhere else: Your apt output contains a list of

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

And that list contains core packages, among them your xserver. So, do try to run the recommended apt autoremove and check the list whether that leaves your system in a useful state before progressing to install more software like wine.

also, why install wine32:i686, and not simply wine32?

@MarcusMüller the autoremove is empty, thers is no packages to delete. At the top of the post are the previously executed commands.

When I try install any .exe package, it recommends me install wine32:i386

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: from your output tells a different story!

@MarcusMüller I posted the output of different commands in this thread

@MarcusMüller you’re misreading the output (which isn’t surprising, because it is confusing): when apt says “the following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required”, it includes the results of the package removals it is about to process — it should really say “after this command completes, the following packages will no longer be required”.

@StephenKitt oooooh! Thanks! Sorry, Alexander. I was misguided in saying what I said about unused packages!
